# Proof of Ulam's lemma

Tags: measure-theory

I am looking for a proof of Ulam's lemma, which states that every finite measure $\mu$ on a Borel-$\sigma$-Algebra $B_T$ of a Polish space T is regular, i.e

$\mu(A)=\sup\{\mu(K)|K\text{ compact, }K\subseteq B\}=\inf\{\mu(O)|O\text{ open, } B\subseteq O\}$

A link to a proof or a reference to a book which contains the proof is enough, I just cannot find one online.

Comment: I think it's in Klenke's probability book?

Answer (score 1):

One way proof is (approximately) following:

Sicne we have Polish space, then we can find $\displaystyle A_n =\cup_{i=1}^{k_n} B_{1/n}(x_i)$ : $\mu(A \backslash A_n) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2^n}$. Now we can consider $\bar{A} = \cap A_n$ (it will be bounded, closed in $A$, hence compact). And $\mu(A \backslash \bar{A}) < \varepsilon$ (as sum of measures). The same for opposite part.

Comment: Could you expand a little on the construction of these $A_n$ for an arbitrary Borel measurable set $A$? I see why it is true when $A$ is open.